# Why cant you auto-assign EIPs at the subnet level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Its strange to me this feature is missing so I'm assuming maybe there is something fundamental I dont understand about this.

At the subnet level I can enable "Auto-assign Public IP" to automatically assign ephemeral public IPs to any new instances launched in the subnet.

But why is there not an "Auto-assign Elastic IP" here? Why can't I have an EIP automatically allocated and assigned to new instances launched in the subnet? Would auto-assigning EIPs be problematic in some way?

Or maybe this is Amazon just trying to dissuade customers from reserving a lot of their address space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, such option will get a lot of customers into trouble.

1. Should we allocate new EIP or assign an existing one if we have an unassigned EIP?
2. Should we release EIP once the instance is terminated?
3. What would happen if we have some autoscaling policy that creates a new instance every 10 minutes? Will a (pretty expensive) new EIP be allocated each time?

**Architecturally, EIPs are not for servers/instances. They are for services.** So assigning EIP to an instance right away doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i agree it doesn't make sense in most cases, most applications should be using DNS/ELB anyway for resolution. For spinning up a new "pet" server that requires a static IP it would be a convenience though. I dont think there is an option to release an EIP if an instance it is attached to is terminated anyway- so your confronted with this if you attach one manually. But i suppose you could easily proliferate EIPs this way without realizing it